# troubleshooting session persistent issues in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

i need some pointers on how to troubleshoot session problems - right now my session isn't persisting and I am working on an app where I couldn't get a straight communication with the previous programmers.

I found out 2 things.

Using cookies as session store - the session never persist. Eg,

```
def action1
  session[:counter] = 1
  redirect_to action: action2
end

def action2
  # session[:counter] -> this is now nil
end
```

Then i switched my session store to using database, and it will persist on the next action, BUT after i refresh the page, the session is gone and i noticed a new session was created.

There are multiple subdomains happening in the code, but - on my examples, there is no subdomain or we can say the url stays the same all the time.

EDIT:

this could be a clue, so i switched over to active record store, I can see that rails is creating a new session for instance. if i go to /page on browser tab1, go to /page again but on a different tab, rails will create a new session. this goes the same if i refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

OK - not really an answer or an explanation to my issue, but it sort of solve my problem.

The project I am dealing with uses Rails 3.0.5. I replaced it with the lastest Rails version = 3.2.1 and my problems with the session went away.

It would be nice of course if somebody can explain what's with the earlier Rails version and what could be the possibility its messing up  the session - could it be my machine's configuration?